# Cannot find module 'react/lib/warning' - Error with React version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, gulp

I'm trying to run the "gulp nodemon" to check an application made in REACT but I get the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'react/lib/warning'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kevin/hbtn/Fix_My_Code_Challenge/0x01-challenge/react-blog/node_modules/react-bootstrap/lib/BreadcrumbItem.js:23:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/kevin/hbtn/Fix_My_Code_Challenge/0x01-challenge/react-blog/node_modules/babel/lib/babel/api/register/node.js:130:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
```

It seems that the version of REACT with which it was developed is old and had a different distribution of its files.

This is the file where the error occurs:

```
'use strict';

var _objectWithoutProperties = require('babel-runtime/helpers/object-without-properties')['default'];

var _extends = require('babel-runtime/helpers/extends')['default'];

var _interopRequireDefault = require('babel-runtime/helpers/interop-require-default')['default'];

exports.__esModule = true;

var _react = require('react');
var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);
var _classnames = require('classnames');
var _classnames2 = _interopRequireDefault(_classnames);
var _SafeAnchor = require('./SafeAnchor');
var _SafeAnchor2 = _interopRequireDefault(_SafeAnchor);
var _reactLibWarning = require('react/lib/warning');
var _reactLibWarning2 = _interopRequireDefault(_reactLibWarning);
var _propTypes = require('prop-types');
var _propTypes2 = _interopRequireDefault(_propTypes);
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');
var BreadcrumbItem = createReactClass({
  displayName: 'BreadcrumbItem',

  propTypes: {
    /**
     * If set to true, renders `span` instead of `a`
     */
    active: _propTypes2['default'].bool,
    /**
     * HTML id for the wrapper `li` element
     */
    id: _propTypes2['default'].oneOfType([_propTypes2['default'].string, _propTypes2['default'].number]),
    /**
     * HTML id for the inner `a` element
     */
    linkId: _propTypes2['default'].oneOfType([_propTypes2['default'].string, _propTypes2['default'].number]),
    /**
     * `href` attribute for the inner `a` element
     */
    href: _propTypes2['default'].string,
    /**
     * `title` attribute for the inner `a` element
     */
    title: _propTypes2['default'].node,
    /**
     * `target` attribute for the inner `a` element
     */
    target: _propTypes2['default'].string
  },

  getDefaultProps: function getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      active: false
    };
  },

  render: function render() {
    var _props = this.props;
    var active = _props.active;
    var className = _props.className;
    var id = _props.id;
    var linkId = _props.linkId;
    var children = _props.children;
    var href = _props.href;
    var title = _props.title;
    var target = _props.target;

    var props = _objectWithoutProperties(_props, ['active', 'className', 'id', 'linkId', 'children', 'href', 'title', 'target']);

    _reactLibWarning2['default'](!(href && active), '[react-bootstrap] `href` and `active` properties cannot be set at the same time');

    var linkProps = {
      href: href,
      title: title,
      target: target,
      id: linkId
    };

    return _react2['default'].createElement(
      'li',
      { id: id, className: _classnames2['default'](className, { active: active }) },
      active ? _react2['default'].createElement(
        'span',
        props,
        children
      ) : _react2['default'].createElement(
        _SafeAnchor2['default'],
        _extends({}, props, linkProps),
        children
      )
    );
  }
});

exports['default'] = BreadcrumbItem;
module.exports = exports['default'];
```

And this is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "React-Isomorphic-Blog",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React Isomorphic Blog",
  "author": "Jonathan Rossi <jonathan.m.rossi@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "alt": "^0.14.5",
    "babel": "^4.7.16",
    "body-parser": "^1.12.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.3.4",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
    "express": "^4.12.3",
    "express-session": "^1.10.4",
    "iso": "^4.0.2",
    "jade": "^1.9.2",
    "marked": "^1.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.10.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.26.2",
    "react-ga": "^2.1.2",
    "react-prop-types": "^0.4.0",
    "react-router": "^3.2.6",
    "superagent": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^16.5.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-print": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.3.7",
    "reactify": "^1.1.0",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "app": "./src/client.js"
  },
  "dest": {
    "app": "bundle.js",
    "dist": "public/scripts/react"
  },
  "main": "bin/www.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --use_strict bin/www.js"
  }
}
```

I'm new to React, I've already solved many other mistakes that have come up, but for this one I couldn't find a solution. Can you help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: hey kevin, are you working with this code directly? like this code isn't transpiled from babel or anything?

Comment: Hey there, the code isn't mine, how could I know?